# Automatically assign values from a day before when today's data is not present

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains columns such as Price_Date, Catagory, Size, Grade, Country, and Price. The table sometimes do not contain data for Sundays or holidays (like christmas, thanksgivings, etc).

What I am trying to achieve here is when the table do not contain data for certain date, I want it to automaticaly populate data from the pervious day.

For example, the table do not contain 01/06/2019 data. It does not have the date at all. In this case, I want to automatically assign 01/06/2019 date which was missing and populate it with 01/05/2019 data.

---

```
Price_Date            Catagory  Size    Grade   Country Price
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-01-05              0        32      1         2    24.25
2019-01-05              0        36      1         2    24.25
2019-01-05              0        40      1         2    24.25
2019-01-05              0        48      1         2    24.25
2019-01-05              0        60      1         2    23.25
2019-01-05              0        70      1         2    21.25
2019-01-05              0        84      1         2    17.25
```

Here is the SQL query that I came up with.

And sorry if I am making this post in a wrong section.

```
WITH MyRowSet
   AS
   (
         select distinct 
                       d.date_key
                       ,p.Size_Value
                       ,Catagory_Value
                       ,cast (Price_Date as datetime) as prev_effex
                       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date_key,Size_Value,Catagory_Value order by date_key,cast (Price_Date as datetime)  desc) AS RowNum
         from
         FSPPRICE  P 

          CROSS APPLY Dim_Time d
         where

         d.Date_KEY <(GETDATE()) and                           

         (D.Date_KEY > (select min(cast (Price_Date as datetime)) as min_date from FSPPRICE))

         and

         cast (Price_Date as datetime) <> D.Date_Key and cast (Price_Date as datetime) < D.Date_Key


         group by  d.date_key,Price_Date,Size_Value,Catagory_Value

  )
    SELECT 
                       r.Date_KEY AS effectiveon
                       ,P.Catagory_Value
                       ,cast(P.Size_Value as varchar) as Size_Value
                       ,P.Grade_Value
                       ,P.Country
                       ,P.Price
                       ,P.Active_Code
         FROM     MyRowSet AS R INNER JOIN
             FSPPRICE AS P 
             ON r.prev_effex = P.Price_Date and r.Catagory_Value=p.Catagory_Value and r.Size_Value=p.Size_Value WHERE (rownum < 2)
```

Comment: What if the previous day is empty? Looking back arbitrarily many days is more complicated and looking back exactly one day.

Comment: Can you give an example of where the date is missing? Also, how do you figure out that date is missing?

Comment: @Derpy usually only Sundays data is missing but if the previous day data is missing as well I want to pull data from the day before previous day.  for example of 01/05 and 01/06 data are missing I want to assing 01/04 data.

Comment: So you are missing 01/06 data, and for 01/05, you have 7 records, what you want is to copy these 7 records of 01/05 to be 7 records for 01/06? correct?

Comment: @Jarlh I am using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot So the table I am talking about has prices for each day and usually it does not have sunday data. But the other table has packing dates and it contains Sundays date as well . I want to join these two tables and get the price for sunday. Technically there is no price assigned on Sundays but I want to pull the price from Saturday for Sunday packing dates.

Comment: @Jyao Correct! Copy records from 01/05 to 01/06 when 01/06 records do not exist

Comment: Well, it is doable. you are missing join condition in your cte and any idea aobut the columns in both the table?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot The other table is a Packing table and it is larger than the Price table and contains numerous columns. The Packing table has PackDates column which contains Sundays data as well. It also has Price column which gets its value from the Price table. However the Price table do not contain Sunday data. I have to join these two tables on Dates, Grades, Sizes, Catagory, and Country, and copy Saturday's records to Sunday (including the price).

Can you let me know which join condition am I missing in my CTE? Thanks!

Comment: @user9435302 ok, next question. Are you only concerned with determining the current day's effective pricing, or do you need the pricing history too? Or in other words, are you only inspecting one day at a time?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @dt date = GETDATE();--any given date
select @dt as price_date, category, size, grade, grade, country, price
from 
    @t
where price_date in (select MAX(price_date) price_date from @t where price_date <= @dt)
```